# Why am I losing reputation while I was offline?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

I was offline for 15 days from Stack Overflow. I had 700+ reputation before. But when I logged in after 15 days, I found a lot of answers and pending responses for me. Also, my reputation get deducted. Now it became 503. This has happened thrice to me. Can anyone inform me why this thing happens here?

Comment: You're getting votes confused with reputation points.

Answer (score 11):

You had two accounts with a lot of cross voting that were merged together.

Not notifying you was my mistake.  When I merged the accounts I was at work where GMail is blocked.  I meant to email you when I got home, but I forgot.  I apologize for the oversight.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably the [anti fraud vote mechanism](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/).

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915494/seed-mechanism-does-not-work-fine-for-blackberry/1899205#1899205), he answered his own question (legit), and then thanked himself in a comment (not legit).

Comment: maybe he has two accounts and made a mistake.

Comment: For me it seems like it was meant to look like it was another one who did the "thanks". So the puppet giving himself points. Then the puppet was merged.

Comment: Is this the same account that was discussed earlier on meta with a lot of self-thanking?  Although of course I'm sure there's been dozens of cases of this...

Comment: Ahahahahahahahahaha! And to then come to Meta and complain about it. The cheek! @Ether there was this prominent example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41660/convincing-a-stack-overflow-user-to-switch-careers Sock-puppeteering was only a sideshow there, though.

Comment: @Pekka: This question is (mostly) clear, and hasn't been flagged as a duplicate, and has a specific answer. Mind you, I'd be a bit embarrassed at the answer.