# My Reputation on SO is reduced by 1K !

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

I dont understand why, but today when I loggedin to my SO Ac , my reputation is 874. I am logging in after 3 days and this is what I am seeing. Earlier it was 2K + something. I can't see a reason for this.

Comment: Dupe many times over. Your rep got recalculated. This is normal.

Comment: @Billy That's a pretty epic loss for just a recalc

Comment: @Michael this really should have been sent to team@stackoverflow.com ... there is no bug here

Comment: @waffles Well, it should've been tagged [support], but I was saying 1200 rep from a 2000 rep user being lost to deleted posts is unusually high; it was probably spam posts or vote-spam detection like [dmckee said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69665/my-reputation-on-so-is-reduced-by-1k/69668#69668)

Comment: @waffles, if it's not a bug, then how about revealing what happened.

Comment: @Lance an account was merged

Comment: @Waffles How did merging an account cause such a significant rep loss?

Comment: @Kragen: I have no specific knowledge of this case, but that effect *can* be produced by lots of cross-upvoting.

Answer (score 6):

Large losses usually mean either

- multiple posts judged as spam or offensive and deleted (your profile shows no signs of this)
- a lot of modest losses all hitting at one due to a rep recalc (likely if you have had many questions deleted)
- a great many votes deleted because they were judged to have originated from sock-puppets or a mutual admiration arrangement

Comment: Does /reputation show losses from flagged posts? I guess probably not since they've been deleted

Comment: If it's the third, there should be a message saying "We've noticed your behaviour. This is why you lost your reputation. You don't need to thank us for it."

Comment: @Michael Actually, you get a special entry for flag-deleted posts. [PostId 12](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678), if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: In one case of cross-voting, a higher-up [said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59175/why-am-i-losing-reputation-while-i-was-offline/59180#59180) the cross-voter should have been notified by email, but wasn't by mistake. It sounds like this person wasn't notified either.